# Fragment Tab adapter getItem calling twice

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created swipe tab with three different fragments for three tabs. All the three tabs are getting dynamic data from webservice. on load, my first tab Tab1 is showing Tab2 data. getItem method in FragmentPagerAdapter is called twice.

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return  new Tab1;
            case 1:
                return new Tab2;
            case 2:
                return new Tab3;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

How can i load fragment one only when Tab1 is loaded.

Comment: it is the expected behavior. The ViewPager caches an additional page

Comment: and that's ok. You should change your logic to handle this.

Comment: my Tab1 is showing Tab2 data . Any possible way that tab1 shows the correct data even if additional page is cached

Answer (score 0):

**How can i load fragment one only when Tab1 is loaded.**

You can't.

I believe you are using ViewPager. It is the cause of calling getItem() twice. This is how ViewPager works. It loads previous fragment, current fragment and next fragment to allow you smooth scroll between pages.

In your case you are on tab1 so first and second page is loaded (previous page is not loaded because it doesn't exist)

When you scroll from tab1 to tab2 - tab3 will be loaded and so on

You can set how many tabs to left and right will be cashed using `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit` but min value is 1 and it is default too.

Comment: Yes i have used ViewPager. But my Tab1 is not showing its data. Its showing Tab2 data. Any solution for this.